# I've installed gatsby in my pc but I'm still having an error message

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I've been having this issue on windows, saying:

[image]

> sharp@0.23.2 not installed and a couple of other modules not installed
>   too like node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy &&
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like last version of Sharp working on 32bits environment is v0.11.4 and you're trying to install 0.23.2. according to this issue: 
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/379

and Gatsby documentation:

> Some plugins which depend on native NPM dependencies require the Node
>   x64 build of Node.js. If you’re struggling to install
>   gatsby-plugin-sharp, try installing Node x64 and removing node_modules
>   and running npm install.

Also, you could try to follow those recommendations from Gatsby documentation, like installing windows build tool:

> The recommended way to setup your build environment on Windows is to
>   install the windows-build-tools package by running npm install
>   windows-build-tools -g on an admin PowerShell console

Source:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/

It should resolve many of your problems.